# Is it possible to store the AppLovin SDK key in a JSON file instead of the manifest.xml

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hey fellow Android developers,

I'm currently integrating the AppLovin SDK into my Android app, and I'm wondering if there's a way to keep my sensitive SDK key separate from the manifest.xml file. I've been trying to find a way to store the AppLovin SDK key in a JSON file or some other secure manner, but I haven't come across a clear solution yet.

Has anyone successfully managed to achieve this? If so, could you share your approach or any resources you found helpful? I believe this would not only enhance security but also make it easier to manage different SDK keys for different build configurations.

Looking forward to hearing your insights and experiences.

Thanks in advance

https://i.imgur.com/iKHwB2k.png

Answer (score 0):

We have that key coming from server, so you can read your JSON file and provide key yourself.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).